# change font color on mouse over

Tags: html, mouseover

I have a table which shows the results of my MYSQL Query. To this table I have added row highlighting as you can see in the code below this works perfectly well.  However what I am trying to do  is also change the color of the font as the row is highlighted, but not with much success.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
 <tr class="active" bgcolor="#222222" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#222222';" onMouseOver="Color='gold';">                  
            <td height="40" align="left" class="nrmgrid4" onMouseOver="Color='red';" ><div id="master_row"><?php echo "$timedate"; ?></div></td>
            <td align="left" class="nrmgrid4" onMouseOver="Color='red';"><div align="left"><?php echo "<a href=\"visitor-detailpage.php?id={$id}\">$company_name</a>";?></div></td>
            <td align="center" class="nrmgrid4" onMouseOver="Color='red';" ><?php echo "$region_name"; ?></td>
            <td align="center" class="nrmgrid4" onMouseOver="Color='red';" ><?php echo "$page_views"; ?></td>
            <td align="center" class="nrmgrid4" onMouseOver="Color='red';"><?php echo "$referrer"; ?></td>
            <td align="center" class="nrmgrid4" onMouseOver="Color='red';"><?php echo "$search_term"; ?></td>
            <td align="center" class="nrmgrid4" onMouseOver="Color='red';">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" class="nrmgrid4" onMouseOver="Color='red';"><?php echo "<a href=\"editVisitorList.php?id={$id}\">Edit</a>";?></td>
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line :

```
<tr class="active" bgcolor="#222222" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#222222';" onMouseOver="Color='gold';">
```

To :

```
<tr class="active">
```

And you must write **CSS** :

```
tr.active{ background-color: #222222; }
tr.active:hover{
   background-color: gold;
   color: gold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a much cleaner way of doing it, and never considered it.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For changing `color` of hover row,you can use this:

```
tr:hover
{
   color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, yes, but it only changes the colour if you hover over that particular column, and I want to change the colour of all of the text in that row.

Comment: @SamWilliams use my new answer

Answer (score 0):

```
tr.active:hover{
color:gold;
```

}

and you can get your desired result with CSS if you use class or ID wisely.